# Convert single quotes (apostrophe) in a string to correct opening and closing quotes

Tags: regex, julia

I have strings that contain some single quotes (`'`) and I'd like to educate the quotes (ie turn them into `‘` and `’`. My regex on this (peculiar) test string is giving me some problems:

```
s = "'Twas the night before Christmas. 'Pchnąć w tę łódź jeża Żywioł, jaźń, Świerk!' 
      This is 'tricky' aka 'It's not easy'. Or 'Non-trivial'. "
s = replace(s, r"\B'\b([^'\r\n]+)\b'\B" => s"‘\1’")
s = replace(s, r"(\w)'(\w)" => s"\1’\2")
println(s)
```

The correct output should be:

> ’Twas the night before Christmas. ‘Pchnąć w tę łódź jeża Żywioł, jaźń, Świerk!' 
>   This is ‘tricky’ aka ‘It’s not easy’. Or ‘Non-trivial’. "

but I'm only catching some of them:

> 'Twas the night before Christmas. 'Pchnąć w tę łódź jeża Żywioł, jaźń, Świerk!' 
>   This is ‘tricky’ aka 'It’s not easy'. Or ‘Non-trivial’.

Any help from Julia/regex ‘wizards’ would be appreciated!

Comment: It would seem to me that you would need to distinguish the "outer" quotes from the "inner" one in the case of `'This is daycaster's problem.'`. But this is a classic case of trying to recognize balanced tokens (`'` in both cases), which regular expressions cannot do.

Comment: `'Twas` is quite a specific case, I doubt this is something you can generalize. I think it can be solved with `s = replace(s, r"(?i)\B'((?:t(?:is|was|will|shall)|more|exceptions|here)\b)" => s"’\1"); s = replace(s, r"\b'\b" => s"’");  s = replace(s, r"'([^']*)'" => s"‘\1’")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contractions with a `'` at the beginning are a bit of a problem and require special casing.

You also seem to have a typo in your desired output (`Świerk!'` instead of `Świerk!’`)

The following function should work in most cases:

```
function educate(s)
    s = replace(s, r"'(?=twas|twere|til|tis)"i => s"’") # handle contractions with a ' at the beginning
    s = replace(s, r"(\w)'(\w)" => s"\1’\2") # handle normal contractions
    s = replace(s, r"s'" => s"s’") # this is either something like "the girls' toys" or the end of a quote, but we don't care
    s = replace(s, r"(?<=[\s\,\.])'(?=\S)(.+?)(?<!\s)'(?=[\s\,\.])" => s"‘\1’") # quotations where the right side doesn't end with an "s'"
    s = replace(s, r"'" => s"‘") # everything we haven't caught yet should be a "‘"
    s
end

# Your test case:
s = "'Twas the night before Christmas. 'Pchnąć w tę łódź jeża Żywioł, jaźń, Świerk!' This is 'tricky' aka 'It's not easy'. Or 'Non-trivial'."
target = "’Twas the night before Christmas. ‘Pchnąć w tę łódź jeża Żywioł, jaźń, Świerk!’ This is ‘tricky’ aka ‘It’s not easy’. Or ‘Non-trivial’."
educate(s) == target # true

# Slightly trickier:
s = " 'Twas the night before Christmas. 'Pchnąć w tę łódź jeża Żywioł, jaźń, Świerk!' This is 'tricky' aka 'It's not easy'. Or 'Non-trivial'. 'The girls' teachers' stuffs'"
target = " ’Twas the night before Christmas. ‘Pchnąć w tę łódź jeża Żywioł, jaźń, Świerk!’ This is ‘tricky’ aka ‘It’s not easy’. Or ‘Non-trivial’. ‘The girls’ teachers’ stuffs’"
educate(s) == target # true
```

Answer (score 1):

`'Twas` is quite a specific case, I doubt this is something you can generalize.

I think it can be solved with

```
s = replace(s, r"(?i)\B'((?:t(?:is|was|will|shall)|more|exceptions|here)\b)" => s"’\1")
s = replace(s, r"\b'\b" => s"’")
s = replace(s, r"'([^']*)'" => s"‘\1’")
```

**NOTES**

- The first `replace` deals with special cases (contractions)
- The second one replaces all `'` in between word chars (you may enforce matching between letters only with `(?<=\p{L})'(?=\p{L})`)
- The third one replaces all substrings between two `'` chars with `"..."` substrings.

**NOTE**: This can't solve the Genetive apostrophe with Plural nouns, as in `the boys' game`.